# How to post values outside a partial view to controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with a paginated list like in the NerdDinner sample.

I am trying to show the navigation buttons for forward and back. I want there to be a form post 
when these are clicked so that the search text is still passed in. 
The problem is, the search text is stored in a form that is outside the partial view that the paged list is in and so the controller never finds it.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Does the controller handle your search text value on post?

Comment: Yeah, it's so that it can repopulate the text box and also it uses it for part of the search query

Comment: Are your navigation using POST or GET?

Comment: Post. I havn't got the code handy just now, It was pretty ad hoc. I have a div with main search text box in a form. Then outside that I have a partial view that renders the paged list of results. The paged list seems to work ok when pushing next and previous but the search text of the form isn't passed to the controller so it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider passing not only query results but also the search text to partial view via [view model](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can include

```
<input type="hidden" id="search" />
```

in the form with navigation buttons and fill it on POST using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yourNavButtonsClass').click(function () {
        var searchText = $('input#yourSearchTextBoxId').val();
        $('input#search').val(searchText);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately my solution requires Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

google appends search text to the url, yahoo and msn too. I'm sure you can do the same and this is the better way :)